# Application display error after windows upgrade

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

Hi I have recently upgraded from windows 7 to windows 8.And have installed both Visual studio 2010 and 2012 on my PC.I had two personal application that worked fine under windows 7 but after trying to run them on windows 8 I get the following error.

The first application displays the following error:

```
The database 'E:\PROJECTS IDE\VISUAL STUDIO\2010\WEBAPPLICATIONS\FORUM\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'E:\PROJECTS IDE\VISUAL STUDIO\2010\WEBAPPLICATIONS\FORUM\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file E:\Projects IDE\Visual Studio\2010\WebApplications\Forum\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
```

This seems to be linked to the ASPNETB.MDF db on both applications.

The second applications runs fine at first but I thing only because I have created with two database and in order to run the app acces to ASPNETDB.MDF is not required.But after I try to login into the application I get this error:

```
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file D:\Projects IDE\Visual Studio\MyWork\Websites\e-commerce\e-commerce\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
```

The reason I am posting both the application problems is because I thing it is the same problem that is preventing my applications from running.

What can I do to solve this problem?